# I cant count time period

Tags: java

I have code which checks if the given "A" time (in milliseconds) is in the given "b" time period.

```
private static boolean isInTimeInterval(long time, int timePeriod) {

        long curTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        // time period is in hours, 1 hour is 3600000 ms;
        long startTime = curTime - timePeriod * 3600000; 
        if (time >= startTime && time < curTime){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I take the time from a file and parse it into a `long` like this:

```
(Long.parseLong(array[2]))
```

But it doesn't work correctly, what is wrong ?

Comment: Let me ask you: What is wrong? Tell us the issue you are having it would be easier for us to help.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly?  When you take your car to the garage to get it fixed do you say "my car isn't working properly"?

Comment: @Alex I get that, but why? Is he having troubles with the parsing of he long, with the function, etc? He could provide some example executions in which this thing fails, because it looks ok so far.

Comment: @Alex , no it doesn't :(

Comment: Can you print out the values you are comparing to make sure the value parsing from the file is working as expected?

Comment: @Arno I can appreciate it doesn't work correctly, but think: what should it do?.What is it doing instead?  When you step through with a debugger, what's going wrong, and where?  How are we to know the problem when you don't tell us what it is?

Comment: @Alex it returns false when It must return true

Comment: What does the data in your file look like?  Is it actually a long value, or is it a timestamp that you'd need to parse and then convert to a long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify things, I would suggest that you first subtract the start time from the end time, check to see if that is positive and then decide if the remaining milliseconds is smaller than the requested time period.

```
long difference = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - time;
long timeRange = timePeriod * 3600000;
return (0 <= difference && differance <= timeRange);
```

It makes the code slightly smaller in lines, but more importantly, it simplifies the math to where you know the code isn't the problem.

As far as the errors you are likely encountering, I'd look to your

```
Long.parseLong(array[2])
```

As that is likely grabbing the input in a manner you aren't expecting.  For starters, I'd put in some logging or at least one-time `println` debugging statements to verify the input times are what I thought they were.